# React, pass value from if statement to const with template literals

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an exported const that takes two parameters. With these two parameters I'd like to do some if checks and upon hit, set the result to a variable.

In that exported const I also have another const with a template string and that is where I want to add the result from previous `if` statement. Something like this:

```
export const getTest = (typeX, typeY) => {

     let testing = '';
     if (typeX === 'x' && typeY === 'y') {
         testing = 'y';
     }

     const testFormat = `
     <div style='
      color: white;
      font-size: 1rem;
      font-weight: bold;
      background: {series.color};'
      >
      {point.y}
     </div>
    `;

    return {
     headerFormat: '',
     testFormat,
     useHTML: true,
     padding: 0,
    };
};
```

In `testFormat` I have **{point.y}** which is working perfectly from where it's at, but how should I approach to have **testing** (from the if statement) next to it?

Like **{testing} {point.y}**

Comment: Are you seeing nay error with  {testing} {point.y} approach?

Comment: Does this achieve what you want? `<div style='
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: {series.color};'
  >
${testing}  {point.y}
 </div>
`

Comment: @DacreDenny AH! there we have it! ${testing} did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: @mtorn you're welcome 

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to insert `${testing}` into your template string for `testFormat` like so:

```
const testFormat = `
 <div style='
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: {series.color};'
  >
  ${testing} {point.y}
 </div>
`;
```

By adding `${testing}` to your string, this causes the value for variable `testing` to be inserted into the template string at that point in the resulting string value for `testFormat`.